# SQL Attribute is a list - Access one element of the list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table `X` with an attribute `names | character varying(255)[]`.

Now, the `names` in one entry could be `{ 'mary' , 'james' , 'john' }`. How do I run a query which would be something along the lines -

```
select names,other_attribute_1 from X where 'mary' in names ;
```

I need to fetch all (or some attributes) of a row where the names list has 'mary'.

Comment: What is `other_attribute_1` ?

Comment: It could be anything, just some another attribute corresponding to an entry

Comment: Why do you store multiple values in a single column? You should read up on normalization.

Comment: The table structure is that way, I have simplified the situation to make the question clear !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT names,
  other_attribute_1 
FROM x 
WHERE names LIKE '%mary%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT names, other_attribute_1 
FROM x
WHERE name = 'mary'
```

Or if it has different spellings (doesn't really apply to the name mary, but John for example) use `IN`.

```
SELECT names, other_attribute_1 
FROM x
WHERE name in ('john', 'jon')
```

Or if it had apostrophes or plurals such as mary's or marys use `LIKE`.

```
SELECT names, other_attribute_1 
FROM x
WHERE name LIKE 'mary%'
```